# Why are constant current drivers 10% less efficient than constant voltage drivers?

Tags: led, power, led-driver

I want to drive a CREE XP-G3 LED with 2.73V, 350mA. My power supply is a car battery (10.5-14.5V).

I went to the Texas Instruments website and inputted the above specs into their WEBENCH designer, once for a constant voltage supply and once for a constant current supply. The constant current regulators topped out at 83% efficiency but the constant voltage ones reached 89%+ I looked on Digi-key for non-TI parts and it was a similar story for my specs.

Is there a fundamental architecture difference between constant-current and constant voltage regulators? They both look like their feedback input is just a voltage.

If all my Cree XP-G3 LEDs are the same, can I just use a constant voltage supply tuned to 2.73V?

Constant voltage:
[image: Constant voltage]

Constant current: 
[image: Constant current]

Comment: You should NEVER attempt to drive bare LEDs from a constant-voltage power supply, as the actual voltage required for a particular LED current will vary between LEDs, depending on temperature, production batch, phase of the moon, and other unknown reasons.

Comment: One possible explanation is that a current driver needs to sense the current. That normally entails a current sense resistor to generate a feedback voltage. Your current, multiplied by the voltage drop across the sense resistor will be dissipated as heat.

Comment: in the real world, for LEDs, voltage driven has worse efficiency due to the ballast resistor. Also, there are so MANY more parts available for constant voltage that its easy for the computer to optimize to 90%+ for your specific application.

Comment: @Mark -- that doesn't really hold water as current mode constant voltage converters *also* need a current sense function, and this can be done using FET Rds(on) or inductor DCR instead of a dedicated sense resistor as well.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, most of the LED drivers I've seen (for back-lights and such) are designed to measure current on the low-side and have a relatively high reference voltage (e.g., 0.8 or 0.2). I believe this really is part of it. They are typically boost so they can't really use the Rds on, at least not the same way a buck would. Of course, I don't know which units the OP used for comparison.

Comment: @mkeith -- in a boost situation (say for backlights from 1S Li-Ion), you're probably right.  However, the OP's dealing with buck all the way here...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, OK. I guess I should have actually read the post.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, But a voltage regulator often doesn't have the same accuracy in its current loop as a current regulator, as it's typically just for over-current protection. I would never use the Rds(on) of a FET to measure current if I needed any accuracy. I would be surprised if you could find a current regulator without a current-sense resistor.

Comment: @Mark -- you clearly have never looked at a current-mode converter control loop lately. :)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, Your right, I haven't looked at a current-mode converter lately, but I have designed more than my share of current regulators, many of them to drive LEDs, And I have always used a sense resistor. I've tried FET sensing, but Rds(on) varies too much with voltage, temperature and current so it's impossible to get any accuracy

Comment: The first IC (constant voltage one) is probably optimized for lower voltage (around 2.7V) output. For example, the synchronous lower switch is part of that optimization. The second IC is not optimized for lower voltage. For example, a diode as lower switch is generally bad for efficiency at 2.7V. I think constant current "high-power" LED drivers are commonly not optimized to drive just 2.7V, but instead a string of LEDs.

Comment: The Vf of an LED can vary due to manufacturing and temperature. That leads to significant output power variation when driven with a fixed voltage. So you don't want to drive with a fixed 2.7V unless you are under-powering the LEDs and are not too concern about inconsistent power output.

Answer (score 1):

You lose a little efficiency due to the difference between Vin and Vout.

String 3 LEDs in series.  You can adjust your current down to the same power level or use lower power LEDs.

You did not set up Workbench correctly.

- Click the Efficiency ">>" twice to get it to max efficiency.
- Recalculate
- Select All Part Types

[image]